# How can I use ExecutorService to get results of all the tasks submitted?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, future, executorservice

I have a requirement where I have to launch 5 threads for 5 tasks and there's a specific timeout for the task to be completed. After timeout I want the results of all the tasks. How can I use ExecutorService for this ?
From what I have read about ExecutorService I concluded I needed something along the lines of :

```
List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
futures.addAll(executor.submit(new someCallable()));
try {
    if (!executorService.awaitTermination(30*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    } 
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    executorService.shutdownNow();
}
```

Should I do a `future.get()` ? What about the interrupted/incomplete threads' result ? I am confused with this part.
In case of failed threads I want to mark their status field=Failed, in case of successful threads, I want to mark them as success.

Comment: In your case, how you want to deal with tasks that failed or didn't complete with the time? Ignore? Fail the whole thing?

Comment: @KennedyOliveira : In case of failed threads I want to mark their status field=Failed, in case of successful threads, I want to mark them as success.

Comment: I think this *could* probably be solved nicely with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#poll-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit- - can one assume that "failing" only means that the task took too long (and not that the internal threads are interrupted or throw an exception) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `invokeAll` from `ExecutorService` with specified timeout - [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

Answer (score 0):

> After timeout I want the results of all the tasks. How can I use ExecutorService for this ?

I would suggest to use [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)

> A task ***that returns a result and may throw an exception***. Implementors
>   define a single method with no arguments called call.

So, when you override `call` method either you return some status or just throw exception case of failure. Then, later using

```
future.get()
```

loop through all your submitted tasks and get their status and accordingly you can update status for further processing.

Comment: yes but how do you associate future and the tasks. I.e. how do you connect which future is for which task ?

Comment: @tejas what do you mean ? when you iterate future, you will get each thread result.

Comment: Sometimes if there's a cancellationException or InterruptedException then in that case future.get doesn't exist.